# Merge arrays from MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to use `array_diff()` command with MySQL, I just can't make it work.

Here is the code:

```
mysqli_select_db($conection, $database);
$query_rsEvents = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY start ASC";
$rsEvents = mysqli_query($conection, $query_rsEvents) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_rsEvents = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEvents);

$array1 = range(9,23);
$array2 =  array_merge(range($row_rsEvents["start"], $row_rsEvents["end"]));

foreach (array_diff($array1, $array2) as $freehours) {
echo "".$freehours."<br>";
}
```

I would like to make all ranges from start and end record and merge it in one array

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: What is your current output and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array2 = array();

while($row_rsEvents = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsEvents)) {
    $array2 = array_merge($array2, range($row_rsEvents["start"], $row_rsEvents["end"]));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.